# SELECT query wtih three tables not going through

Tags: sql

I have problem with `SELECT query` from multiple tables. I have three tables `customer, order and job` and I wan't to use select query to fill dataset and with it datagridview.

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT customer.name, order.date_taken, order.status, job.realisation FROM customer INNER JOIN order ON customer.id = order.id_customer "
```

Code is working fine select query is without `job.realisation`.

In my form I have dropdownlist populated from `job.realisation` table.In job table I have only `ID` and `realisation` columns(realisation as string), but I dont have id_job key in my order table as I'm populating dropwdownlist with items from job.realisation. The thing is that I will like to populate datagridview with SELECT statement above and then add checkboxes on all job.realisiation items that my order contains.

```
[Customer] [OrderDate] [job.realistion1] [job.realistion2] [job.realistion3] 

  ADAM      23.1.2013          x                                   x
  GREG      23.1.2013
```

Answer (score 1):

then you need to join the table `job` on your query,

```
SELECT  customer.name, 
        order.date_taken, 
        order.status, 
        job.realisation 
FROM    customer 
        INNER JOIN order 
            ON customer.id = order.id_customer
        INNER JOIN job
            ON [tableName].[columnName] = job.[columnName]
```

just change the values of `[tableName]` and `[columnName]` to your orignal table name and column name.

Comment: Update my question above...Can you pls look at it. Thx